# Compiling a single F# program on a mac

Tags: macos, f#, mono, visual-studio-code, .net-core

So Im starting to use F# as a language. Currently Im either using Visual studio for **mac** to compile my code or just vscode (and then running MSbuild on the `.fsproj` file). However I find both these solutions **very** inconvenient at times, as I dont want to make projects *every time i want to try out F# code*. Consider c# or C++ or even C. You don't have to make a new project or anything like that, you just type in "gcc ". Im running on a mac and I do have `dotnet` and `mono` installed. Its definitely possible to compile F# to an exe and run it, but how do I do it for only one file? I tried fcs, but Bash doesn't recognize it as a command.

Comment: you can of course just run `fsc` on the file, but the usual way for this type of use case is to use VS or Code and send the fsx file to FSI. No project needed, nothing. That's why it has a REPL, use it :-)

Comment: A) fsc doesnt exist on non windows (to my knowledge) and B) I dont want a repl, id like it to be compiled. Im perfectly aware of F#'s FSI shell/repl, and I agree its pretty useful, but just not for my case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the name of the F# compiler installed with mono is fsharpc.